# Acid vs. Acidic

Tags: word-usage

I’ve always been taught that when a substance has the properties of an acid, it is considered *acidic*.  However, recently I’ve noticed various things describing such substances as *very acid* as if the term were an adjective.  Is this proper usage?  Is it more common in Europe or other English-speaking places? It sounds quite strange to my American ears.

Comment: People often use ***acid*** "adjectivally. In some very common usages, such as [*an **acid** comment*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+acid+comment%2Can+acidic+comment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20acid%20comment%3B%2Cc0), the "morphologically correct" version is so uncommon it can't even be shown on an NGram chart.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? Mine lists it as both a noun and an adjective.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, I checked a dictionary.  While it does list `acid` as an adjective, I have never heard this usage in speech and I didn't know if it was archaic or just more popular elsewhere.

Comment: I think the adjective form tends to be used more in metaphoric senses, e.g. _acid tongue_.

Comment: Surely everyone's heard of acid rain.

Comment: This appears to be a relatively recent phenomenon; [as NGrams show](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+acid%2Cvery+acidic%2Cquite+acid%2Cquite+acidic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20acid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20acidic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquite%20acid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquite%20acidic%3B%2Cc0), `acid` as an adjective seems to have fallen out of favor compared to `acidic`, at least in the last 20-30 years or so.  I'm looking for some reason or explanation behind this.

Comment: If you speak using basic English, you can counteract acid remarks.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann You’re right: that’s a pretty odd-looking sudden trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to UK and US Oxford Dictionary online acid can be used as an adjective meaning the same thing as acidic in reference to PH (not only as in vulgar):

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acid
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/acid

As a native speaker in Australia, I can vouch for "acidic" being the more common adjective, but not the one and only. One of our chief popular-science-celebrities, Karl Kruszelnicki (who is also Australian), almost always uses the term "acid" over "acidic", perhaps because he's trying to use simplified language to engage a larger audience. He'll often use phrases such as "less acid" or "more acid".

Here is an example of him talking about acidification in oceans - you'll get the idea. 
http://mpegmedia.abc.net.au/science/podcast/gmis/gmis20121211.mp3